# Parse facebook JSON data

Tags: android, json, facebook

I have problem with parsing Facebook JSon data my data formate is like this.I googled lot spend much time for this but didn't get the value.Please suggest me how to solve this problem.Your valuable answer will be great appreciated.

**Json**

```
{
   "id": "",
   "name": "",
   "first_name": "",
   "middle_name": "",
   "last_name": "",
   "link": "",
   "username": "",
   "birthday": "",
   "location": {
      "id": "",
      "name": ", "
   }
```

**Update**
Actullay i have 
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=
getting session.getAccessToken() and making it complete url
URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS
                    + session.getAccessToken()
then sending url for http connection and getting Jsonobject 
Problem is this instead of jSonObject it gives true falue(not getting why and how)

**Code for httpConnection**

```
public class JsonParsing {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JsonParsing() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            in, HTTP.UTF_8));

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
            json = buffer.toString();

    } finally {
        in.close();
        reader.close();
    }



        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

After that sending this to parser and getting following error

**Logcat**

```
E/JSON Parser( 5660): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value true of type java.lang.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Can you please explain which value you want?

Comment: Please specify the value you want

Comment: Don't post your JSON file. Instead post the language you're working in and the code you've written already to attempt to work with it.

Comment: I have posted sample formate have look i want to fetch this all information

Comment: Dipu I edited your answer try and let me know what happens.

Comment: Same thing getting jobj null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE : replace your function with this

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        InputStream is = null;
        JSONObject jobj = null;
        String json = null;
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();


            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, HTTP.UTF_8));

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                json = buffer.toString();

            } finally {
                is.close();
                reader.close();
            }

            try {
                jobj = new JSONObject(json);
                System.out.println("JSON : " + jobj);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object

        // return JSON String
        return jobj;

    }
```

Try this

This function will iterate your json recursively. Any json will parsed dynamically.

```
private void parseJson(JSONObject data) {

        if (data != null) {
            Iterator<String> it = data.keys();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();
                try {
                    if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray arry = data.getJSONArray(key);
                        int size = arry.length();
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            parseJson(arry.getJSONObject(i));
                        }
                    } else if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        parseJson(data.getJSONObject(key));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Key :" + key);
                        System.out.println("Value :" + data.getString(key));
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Key :" + key);
                        System.out.println("Value :" + data.getString(key));
                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Call this function and see your logcat.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: after parsing url it returns boolean value

Comment: Oh ! god you are on completely wrong track. You have to pass json string to JasonObject() constructor which is return in facbook call respose. you have to pass response of the call to jsonobject and then that json object to parseJson() method.

Comment: superb thanks log it's working and can u plz tell me what was the issue and one thing more if i want to get only particular value then what should i change in parser thanks

Comment: I just replace HttpPost with HttpGet

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40933/discussion-between-biraj-zalavadia-and-dipu)

Answer (score 1):

use following code.

```
 JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result);
      String detail=json.getString("id");
      String image=json.getString("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Facebook Response as a `graphObject` and fetch the value of its keys.

```
GraphObject facebookResponseGraphObject = facebookResponse.getGraphObject();
JSONObject facebookResponseJSONObject = facebookResponseGraphObject.getInnerJSONObject();

String id = json_obj.getString("id");
String name = json_obj.getString("name");
.
.
.
```

`facebookResponse` is the response you are getting in `onCompleted()`